# Detecting cell change in a textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

I copy an html table into a textarea.

[image]

I can detect the line breaks (which would be the rows) with 
explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $resultsPasted))
[image]

but I haven't been able to explode the cells. Any ideas?

If I do an explode of white spaces

```php
foreach ($resultsPastedArray as $resultsRow) {
    $resultsPastedArray[$i] = explode(" ", $resultsRow);
    $i++;
}
```

It just explodes the cells containing written blank spaces
[image]

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the cells are separated by tabs.  Try this:

```
foreach ($resultsPastedArray as $resultsRow) {
    $resultsPastedArray[$i] = explode("\t", $resultsRow);
    $i++;
}
```